# Error SSL Issue npm WIndows

Tags: node.js, windows, ionic-framework

Hello i have problem about SSL when use npm.
I run this command :
npm install ionic

And i get this following error :

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v4.1.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4

npm ERR! Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames: "Host: registry.npmjs.org. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:a.sni.fastly.net, DNS:a.sni.global-ssl.fastly.net"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\xampp\htdocs\receipt_finder\npm-debug.log
```

I already add my corporate certificate using this command

`npm config -g set cafile C:\opt\Cyberoam_Single_CA.pem`

How to handle that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Please issue the following command to loosen the issue with different certificate cn:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

That's all.

Comment: I just noticed the question date, maybe answer of no use, anyways.